# object found null after passing as parameter in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, parameters, nullable

I'm trying to pass an object (instance of a model managed-bean) from a jsf view to a controller managed-bean through a method action from a commandButton. But i found that the object transfered is found null in the controller managed-bean, so the service in question cannot be performed this way.
Here's the concerned part of the view :

```
<h:commandLink  action="#{employee.delete}" value="Delete account">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{empolyee.emp}" value="#{emp}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

And here, the part of the controller managed-bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="employee")
@RequestScoped
public class EmployeeController implements Serializable {
private Employee emp = new Employee();

public Employee getEmp() {
    return emp;
}

public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
    this.emp= emp;
}

public String delete(){
    if (this.emp == null) {return "bad";}  // The execution stopped here, and the outcome corresponded is returned 
    else {    
        employImp.deleteAccount(this.emp);
        return "good";
    }
}
```

Why the object got null after the process ?
Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116382/fsetpropertyactionlistener-sets-null-value-instead-of-intended-value) will help you.

Comment: Where does `#{emp}` come from?

Comment: It's the current instance of the model managed-bean in the current view, and which has to be injected in the property of the controller managed-bean (with getter/setter).
Here's from i inspired this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082958/can-i-pass-an-object-with-a-jsf-param-tag/17576643#17576643)

Comment: @Gamb, thanks for that answer that i've already seen before, but didn't arrive to realize it. The answer is however useful and resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This actionListener will cause the value given by the "value" attribute
to be set into the ValueExpression given by the "target" attribute.

When the listener executes, perform the following:

- Call getValue() on the "value" ValueExpression.
- If value of the "value" expression is null, call setValue() on the "target" ValueExpression with the null value.
- If the value of the "value" expression is not null, call getType() on the "value" and "target" ValueExpressions to determine their property types.
- Coerce the value of the "value" expression to the "target" expression value type following the Expression Language coercion rules. Call setValue() on the "target" ValueExpression with the resulting value.
- If either coercion or the execution of setValue() fails throw an AbortProcessingException.

your experssion #{emp} is evaluated as null, and getEmp is not called (only setEmp with null value), but if you put #{employee.emp}, it will not be null, and getEmp is called then setEmp. One note why are you assigning value to same variable?

I suggested to put :

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{empolyee.emp}" value="#{empolyee.emp1}" />
```

emp1 is another object you created before

Comment: Oeps…  yes…  because the question was so old, I did not expect it to be marked a duplicate just now…  sorry ;-) delete my comment and will delete this one to in a few hours. Maybe delete yours to