# Pass object from <p:dataTable> to <p:dialog> JSF/PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog

I'm trying to pass object `entry` from DataTable (the row where the button was clicked) into a dialog box. There i want to edit data and submit changes with a call on `editEntry(entry)` method.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="dataTableID" value="#{backingBean.uploadedFileData}" var="entry">
         <p:column headerText="Edit">
             <onclick="PF('editEntryDialog').show();"
         </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="Edit Entry" widgetVar="editEntryDialog" height="220" width="450">

         //Dropdowns which are used to edit the entry on the chosen row

        <h:commandButton id="editNewEntryButtonEdit" value="Edit"
            action="#{backingBeann.editEntry(entry)}"/>
   </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

I found this [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839224/pass-parameter-to-dialog-in-the-same-page) but I want to submit after I make some changes in the dialog box. Also I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082958/can-i-pass-an-object-with-a-jsf-param-tag) with `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` but I'm not really sure how to implement it.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks a lot!